# Rrotating image slider + linked images

Tags: jquery, slider, rotation

I am using this rotating image gallery but not able to link the images.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/04/28/rotating-image-slider/

As soon as I turn images to links, the slider stop working.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify the html rather add a jQuery click event to the `li` with a `data-href` attribute. I've always found it safer to do this because of problems like this

```
$('#rm_container li').click(function(){
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-href');
});

<li data-rotation="-5" data-images="rm_container_2" data-href='http://stackoverflow.com' data-transform="rotate(-5deg)" style="-moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);">
```